# Is there a way to destructure a property that has no name from an object?

Tags: typescript

The response I am getting from a fetch() is

```
{errors: {"": [,…]}, type: "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",…}

errors: {"": [,…]}
   "": [,…]
      0: "Error converting value \"field.value\" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'. Path '', line 1, position 13."
status: 400
title: "One or more validation errors occurred."
traceId: "00-fc1fd022e2c5545a24909a8c7a15c38d-f930263d77c54f34-00"
type: "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1"
```

I am able to destructure `errors, status, title, traceId, and type` from the object, but since the destructured `errors` is another object, with a nameless array inside it, I am not sure how to destructure it further to access the array.

Comment: Destructuring is probably hard, but you should be able to access it by `errors[""]`

Comment: Or actually, you should be able to destructure it like this: `const { errors: { "": errorsArray }, ... } = response`. The array should be in `errorsArray`

Comment: Maybe if you share some code showing how you've destructured the object so far, it's easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can destructure that, but you need to provide a valid identifier for it.

```
const res = { errors: { "": ['an error'] } }

const { errors: { "": messages }} = res

console.log(messages) // ['an error']
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUwjAvDA3jBc4jhALgxgCISiBtAcgEMwsc8qBdGAX3YChPRJZNsufEUxkiAWyQQaAcyTsOaRBG68IIADYIAdBpAyAFJIjS5EAJRA)

---

That said, I don't think this is very readable code. It's pretty confusing what's happening here. I think its is probably far more clear to do something like:

```
const messages = res.errors['']
```

---

Lastly, providing data on a property named empty string, is pretty strange. That also seems like a bad idea since it generates confusion like this whole question.